# How to tar.gz all files and directories from a given list of complete paths while maintaining directories and file permissions?

Tags: bash, shell, tar

How do I create a `tar.gz` from

1. A list of FULL PATH files (such as `/root/test/abcd/123.txt` )
2. that includes both directories AND files
3. that preserves the ownership AND permissions of both files and directories when extracted?

This is how my list of files (`dbfiles.log`) looks like:

```
[oracle@test ~]$ cat dbfiles.log
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/initDEVR.ora
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/orapwDEVR
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileDEVR.ora
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/DEVR/control01.ctl
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/DEVR/control02.ctl
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/DEVR/redo01.log
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/DEVR/redo02.log
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/DEVR/redo03.log
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/DEVR/sysaux01.dbf
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/DEVR/system01.dbf
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/DEVR/temp01.dbf
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/DEVR/undotbs01.dbf
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/DEVR/users01.dbf
[oracle@test ~]$
```

This is how I am doing it today:

```
tar -czvf TARFILENAME.tar.gz -T dbfiles
```

However it requires manual permission configuration after extracting. By the way, I have to use `sudo` to extract the file, so directories get `root:root` ownership and not the original `oracle:oinstall` as needed.

I found some references suggesting that tar's flag `--no-recursion` could solve the problem:

```
tar -zcf file.tgz --no-recursion abc --recursion abc/def
```

I believe this is the right approach, but I'm not sure how can I make this work with my file list. Maybe using `find` to go through the list and send output to the tarball? I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: `tar -p` preserves permissions

Comment: Read `man tar` or `info tar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up finding the solution. Here it is in case someone else needs:

```
awk -F/ '{ d=$1; for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) { print d; d=d "/" $i }; print d }' dbfiles | awk '{ if (index(old,$0 "/") != 1) { old=$0; print } }' | tar czvf $LOCALFS/$TARFILENAME.tar.gz --no-recursion -T -
```

Thanks to who have answered my initial question.

Answer (score 1):

for compressing you can use `tar -cvpf filename.tar.gz` directory.

while extracting, use `--same-owner` parameter.
for e.g. `tar -xvzf --same-owner filename.tar.gz`

Comment: A hostile person again removed a usefull comment. So let me add it again: The `tar` command does not implement an option called `--same-owner`, so you seem to use a tar clone. But in your example command line, any tar compatible command needs to use  the argument `--same-owner` as argument to the `f` keyletter. If the tar clone you are using behaves otherwise, it is broken.